# Mapped drive disconnects after reboot (sharing files between Mac and Windows)

Tags: windows-7, networking, mac

Today I shared my files for Mac OS Lion 10.7.2:  `system preference\ Sharing\` select file share and set the permissions for users.

Then I went to my client Windows pc and mapped the drive network via `my computer\network
 map drive network` and typed the ip address of the Mac. Everything was fine.

Later on, I restarted my Mac and then Windows could not see the mapped drive. Everything was gone. The error: one pop up window appears and asks for username and password again, however the username and password I type in is said to be incorrect (I ensured that I did not type the wrong username and password and I tried many times).

Then I went back to Mac and redid everything again and back to pc, redo and I can see the mapped drive again.

My problem is each time I restart my Mac I have to repeat the process.

Is there a way to make the mapping 'permanent' please?

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing a similar issue but between windows 10 and ubuntu server.
After many attempts including what is mentioned in here (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/systemwide-password-amnesia-v2004-build-19041173/232381f8-e2c6-4e8a-b01c-712fceb0e39e?auth=1) that says something about deleting scheduled tasks nothing worked.

But i have found out that there is some conflict between NTFS mapped Drives and Linux samba mapped drive. considering mac os is linux (ok freebsd) based, maybe it is the same issue...

currently i have 2 mapped drives, one to a regular win 10 shared folder and another to a linux server.  no matter what i do, every time i restart or reboot, i have to delete the linux map and redo it from scratch, and it will work fine until the next restart or reboot.

however, if i remove my win 10 mapped drive, then my credentials for the linux mapped drive are preserved and everything works fine.

anyone can help out on this?

Comment: This 'answer' is actually a follow-up question and should become a separate topic.

Answer (score -1):

ej1
yes you are right... i was thinking the same... i came here to ask my question, but it pointed me to this post when i typed int my title... so i was not sure what to do... i thought it would be redundant to create yet another post about the same thing.

I am not here often enough to know what the community here prefers....

but to address the issue, my "work around" - if i can even call it that, was to delete the windows share since i do not use it that often.  so i only had the linux share. then i created a dummy user on that same win 10 and put that windows share on it.  this way when i need to use it, i just switch users.... i know... NOT a Solution... but that's all i could do now until i get enlightened one way or another.